# How to Combine 2 native html form elements together

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, contenteditable

[image]

I am supposed to write code in html, css and js that looks like this, i do understand that it requires the user to enter a city (in a `textarea`) and rent or buy (in a `select`) in html, however how to combine the two using either css or js or something else remains unclear.

Should I even be the native html elements or make custom elements of some sort?
A `contenteditable` rectangular div with an html select seems useful but the amount of control that css gives for this code is also confusing.

Also i am tring to get autocomplete for the city name based off of the name of the city typed, however how to implement this is also confusing. If I choose an API, will it work in the case of a `contenteditable` rectangle? Should I use something like Algolia search considering the styling requirements?

I am stumped here, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: By ‘combine’ d you just mean have the two sit close together side by side, or is there something more to it?

Comment: they just need to sit close